# What is the transformation rule of the transformed graph?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

I tried squeezing my brain to solve this problem. I don't know where I keep making mistakes. $f(x)$ is the pre-image and $g(x)$.
[image]

Here's my attempt:
The pre-image seemed to be reflected across $x$-axis and $y$-axis. First, I translated back the pre-image to the origin to get $(0,6)$ to $(0,0)$. This gives me the initial rule with the translation and reflection:

$y=-g(-(x+4))+10$

Then, the pre-image seemed to be vertically and horizontally stretched. I chose the following key points

$(-4,2)\rightarrow(-2,6)$

$(0,0)\rightarrow(-4,10)$

$(8,6)\rightarrow(-8,7)$.

This gives me a horizontal distance of $12$ between $(-4,2)$ and $(8,6)$, and $6$ between $(-8,7)$ and $(-2,6)$. On the other hand, this gives me a vertical distance of $6$ between $(8,6)$ and $(0,0)$, and $3$ between $(-8,7)$ and $(-4,10)$.

Therefore, the horizontal stretch has a scale factor of $\frac{6}{12}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$ and the vertical stretch has a scale factor of $\frac{3}{6}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$.

This gives the rule:

$y=-\frac{1}{2}g(-2(x+4))+10$

Translating it back 6 units down:

$y=-\frac{1}{2}g(-2(x+4))+4$

But my answer is wrong according to the book. I got the vertical translation wrong. The answer is

$y=-\frac{1}{2}g(-2(x+4))+7$. The book didn't provide a solution that's why I am confused as to how it got 7.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you made was not applying the initial translation to the $f(x)$; you translated the graph six units up without changing the function to $f(x)+6$. The subsequent $\frac{1}{2}$ vertical stretch you applied should have affected that six-unit translation, so at the end you should have only moved the graph down $\frac{1}{2}(6)=3$ units down.

There is a better approach. Determine the transformations in this order: reflections followed by stretches followed by translations (the key here is to do translations **last**).

(1) Reflections - this should be done visually, like you did;  in your example, this would yield $$y = -f(-x)$$

(2) Stretches - again, basically as you did, though you only need two points on the original function as long as they have **different** $\, x$- and $y$-coordinates and for which you know the location in the image. In your example, you could choose any two of the four marked points, as they all have different $x$- and $y$-coordinates, and their location in the image is easily determined. Suppose we take $(0,-6)$ and $(4,4)$; their image points would be $(-4,10)$ and $(-6,5)$ respectively.

Applying the same logic as you did, the horizontal stretch factor is $\frac{|\Delta x'|}{|\Delta x|} = \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$ and the vertical stretch factor is $\frac{|\Delta y'|}{|\Delta y|} = \frac{5}{10} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Combining this with our reflected function yields $$y = -\frac{1}{2} f(-2x)$$

(3) Translations - now, pick a **single** point on the original function (can be one of the points you already used, or another) and its image point. In this example, let's say we use $(-4,2)$ and $(-2,6)$.

Apply the transformations we've determined so far to the point on the original function. In our case, applying the two reflections and stretches to $(-4,2)$ would give us the point $(2,-1)$; comparing this point to the final image point $(-2,6)$ shows that the necessary translations are $4$ units left and $7$ units up, which means our final equation is $$g(x) = -\frac{1}{2} f\left[-2(x+4)\right] + 7$$